# Why the button text it's not wrap_content and gone when I custom Hight and custom background?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-button

Why the button text it's not wrap_content and gone when I custom Hight and custom background?

**XML Code:**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_create"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_3"
            android:text="@string/create"
            android:theme="@style/FontTheme1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please update this question with  background and style you used in this button.

Comment: just make the layout_height at wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the height. Use:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

In any case you don't need a custom background to have rounded corners.
Just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   ....
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
   app:cornerRadius=".."
    .../>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele Mariotti it's working, greats solution :-)